# looping through a csv

Tags: powershell

just wondering if i could do this in powershell, or even a c#/vb.net command line program.

I have data that looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [kalleload.net](http://www.kalleload.net/uploads/qubtqmuikowt.jpg))</sub>

I  have a Teams Table. It looks like this:

| id | teamname | teamcity |

so for example, C2 has the value "Atlanta Braves". I need to split this up into "Atlanta" and "Braves". Data is consistent. for example "New York Mets" is actually "NewYork Mets".

So i need to go through column C and D and insert all the teams (no duplicates into the db).

Comment: Based on your comment below: Is it a database or a CSV file? How do you intend to store the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One line of PowerShell will read in the CSV file and create a custom object for each home and away team listing (with a property for the city name and for the team name).  The last command in the pipeline will eliminate the duplicates.

```
$TeamsAndCities = import-csv -path c:\mycsvfile.csv | foreach-object { $_.away, $_.home | select-object @{Name='City';Expression={$_.split(' ')[0]}}, @{Name='Team';Expression={$_.split(' ')[1]}} } | select-object -unique
```

You can do database access from PowerShell as well, but that might be suited to a new question with some more details about the database you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely code in VBA/VB but...
Something like

```
Dim rngAwayTeam As Range, rngHomeTeam As Range
set rngAwayTeam = Worksheets("YourWorksheet").Range("C2")
set rngHomeTeam = Worksheets("YourWorksheet").Range("D2")
Dim rowOffset As Integer
rowOffset = 1
Do While (rngAwayTeam.Offset(rowOffset,1).Text <> "") 
  'Do something with rngAwayTeam.Offset(rowOffset,1).Text
  'and rngHomeTeam.Offset(rowOffset,1).Text
  rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
Loop
```

There are other ways I'm sure, but, here is what I would do.

Comment: Is this an excel macro? would it be better to use C# so i can use the data classes to easily update my db?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is an excel macro. Again, I rarely use VBA or .Net, just trying to help you out the best I can. You could just use a C# COM object for the database side of things. (Still new, can't comment.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C# console application quite easily.
All you have to do is loop through each line in the file, adding it to an array using split on the comma (,).

Then you can use your array to display the values or retrieve a specific value on a row.